Strange scrolling behavior with a grid of images
Strange scrolling behavior with a grid of images
I'm experiencing a strange issue when scrolling through a grid of images while moving the cursor around. The scroll position occasionally "rolls back" to a slightly earlier position. This behavior occurs under specific conditions, when using these properties simultaneously:

Any filter on .grid-item:hover

aspect-ratio on .grid-item

grid-template with repeat(auto-fill, minmax(...)) on .my-grid (using a static value like repeat(4, 1fr) avoids the issue).

display: flex; on #app


When does it happen?

Mostly when the images don't fully cover their grid items (or are not even close to covering them).

When hovering over items near the top of the screen.

Specifically, when scrolling a hovered item with an active filter out of view and then moving the cursor to hover over a different item.


Reproduction
I’ve created a CodeSandbox to illustrate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/priceless-fermat-mmkh2k


.my-grid {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 50svh;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid green;
  aspect-ratio: 9/16;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.grid-item:hover {
  filter: brightness(110%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#app {
  display: inline-flex;
}
<div id="app">
  <div class="my-div">
    <div class="grid-item"> <img src="URL..." /> </div>
    <div class="grid-item"> <img src="URL..." /> </div>
    <div class="grid-item"> <img src="URL..." /> </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>



Note: Borders are for illustrative purposes only.

No clue what happened but reproducible on Chrome (131.0.6778.86) but not on FireFox.

Might have something to do with this chrome behavior but still seems like a bug as it snap backs to the previously hovered element.

This behavior might be caused by layout reflows triggered by the combination of aspect-ratio on .grid-item and filter on :hover. When hovering an element, the browser may need to recalculate the grid layout, especially when repeat(auto-fill, minmax(...)) is in use, leading to unexpected scroll jumps.
To address this issue, you could try:

Move the aspect-ratio rule: Instead of applying aspect-ratio to .grid-item, apply it to the <img> inside. This will reduce the complexity of the grid item's layout recalculation.

Use object-fit: Add object-fit: cover; or object-fit: contain; to the <img> elements to preserve their original aspect ratio and ensure they fill their container correctly.


.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid green;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 9/16;
    object-fit: contain; /* or `cover`, depending on your needs */
  }
}

